# Basic questions about Verilog

Tags: verilog

Why adding the concatenation operator can rand a postive value from 0~59?

```
reg [23:0] rand;
rand = {$random} % 60;
```

Why the concatenation operator {} can make such difference?

Comment: Note that `rand` has become a reserved keyword in later versions of SystemVerilog, and you should be using `$urandom` instead of `$random`.

Comment: @dave_59 the question is about verilog, not sv. there is no $urandom in verilog.

Comment: @Serge, Verilog is no longer an active language standard. Even so, most simulators that already support SystemVerilog do not distinguish between Verilog and SystemVerilog system tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from IEEE-1364

> *17.9.1 $random function.* The system function $random provides a mechanism for generating random numbers. The function returns a new 32-bit random number each time it is called. The random number is a **signed** integer; it can be *positive* or *negative*.

Result of concatenation `{}` is always an unsigned number. This is not spelled explicitly in the standard, but even the example (from the standard) which you cited implies it.

There is no difference between signed and unsigned numbers in their bit representations. Only certain operation care about the signs of the operands, including `%`.

A 32-bit signed integer can represent values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, therefore the results of `$random % 60` will be between -59 and 59.

A 32 bit unsigned integer can represent values between 0 and 4,294,967,295, therefore the result of `{$random} % 60` will be from 0 to 59.